# How to connect to the Internet (DSL) automatically at startup?

Tags: networking, startup, dsl

I also have to enter a password to connect. Not the root password, but a password I created for the DSL connection when installing Ubuntu.

So I would like to get rid of the password and connect automatically at startup.

Comment: does the modem (if you are using one) have an ethernet connection available?

Comment: @Roland Taylor Yes, it does. It's the Speedtouch modem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use [`pppoeconf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/pppoeconf.8.html).

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or go to Applications -> Accessories -> Terminal. Run:

```
sudo pppoeconf
```

Set the username and password.

Now to connect, run this [`pon`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/pon.1.html) command in the terminal:

```
sudo pon dsl-provider
```

To disconnect:

```
sudo poff
```

We really want it to connect automatically though, so edit `/etc/rc.local` by running:

```
gksu gedit /etc/rc.local
```

That opens the file in a text editor. Before the line that says `exit 0`, add these lines:

```
# For PPP auto-connect.
killall pppd
ifconfig eth0 up
pon dsl-provider
```

Save file and quit the text editor.

Now, reboot the system.

If you want to use Network Manager, see this articlepost:

- [Fix DSL pppoe connection problem with Network Manager in Ubuntu 9.10](http://ubuntuguide.net/fix-dsl-pppoe-connection-problem-with-network-manager-in-ubuntu-9-10)

Comment: Based on the post you linked, my provider is trying to connect automatically, but Ubuntu is asking for a password. Again, it's not the root nor the service provider password, it's a password I created for the DSL connection when installing Ubuntu.

I have the 'Connect automatically' box checked. So my only problem seems to be the password preventing it to connect automatically.

Comment: I was wrong. 'Auto eth0' was connecting automatically. I checked the 'Available to all users' box and followed your instructions. Now it's connecting automatically. Checking the 'Available to all users' box prevent it from asking for the password. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have it set up with a default account that bypasses the login screen then this is an issue with the keyring. You need to go to

System > Preferences > Passwords and Encryption Keys

You need to delete the Default Keyring and set the Login Keyring as default. I think it might require a restart for it to show up.

Comment: I deleted the Default keyring and set the Login keyring as default and restarted. It was not connecting. I had to delete that connection and create anther one. After I created another one, it started asking for the password again. I checked the 'Available to all users' box and it stopped asking for the password.