# Set default internet connection in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: internet-connection

I have created a DSL connection on my Ubuntu 11.04 and have checked the "Connect Automatically" option in it.

Though, when I start my PC, I get to see "Wired Network Disconnected - You are now Offline"  and to get internet working, I have to select the DSL option in the Network Connections menu in the tray at the top.

So, how to make my DSL connection as the default connection?

**edited**

I have noticed that if I let modem to start before actually starting Ubuntu then, on startup Ubuntu connects to DSL automatically. Therefore, the problem lies in reconnecting to a connection automatically.

Is there an option for the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/13674/how-to-connect-to-the-internet-dsl-automatically-at-startup

Comment: @Web-E that does contain useful info and looks somewhat related, but I think this question is not a duplicate because the other question is about removing a password on the DSL link, and this question is about configuration permanence.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **network manager** -> **Edit connection**.

Then go to -> **DSL Connection**. Your existing connection should be there.Click on **Edit**

Check the tick box to connect automatically. See the below pictures

[image]

Click on OK to exit. Now it should connect automatically.
Let us know if it works.

---

*Accept the correct answer to help others.*

Comment: I had done it already, though when I start my modem well before opening my PC, then it connects automatically otherwise it poses the same problem of being disconnected. Therefore, the problems seems to be of not reconnecting automatically.. Is there a solution for reconnecting automatically?