# Network-manager not running?

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, network-manager

I am able to connect to a WiFi but as I connect my LAN cable for Internet it says that network-manager not running and the I am unable to connect to even WiFi.

Comment: try `sudo service network-manager start`
`

Comment: Yes tried that too but the problem still remains the same that the moment I attach the Lan cable for Internet connection It displays that network manager not running and after that I am unable to connect to even wifi.. :(

Comment: I am using Kubuntu so is it the problem with kubuntu... Also to again connect to the wifi I need to restart my kubuntu

Comment: ok I had solved one problem I had installed WICD but now I want to configure DSL connection in it how can I do that...

Comment: you can do it in **Network Connections**. See [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-up-a-Network-in-Ubuntu) for step by step  guide with picture.

Comment: Hey thanks Guru. I also found out one way to connect to my PPPOE/DSL connection the solution is provided here in below given link

http://askubuntu.com/questions/13674/how-to-connect-to-the-internet-dsl-automatically-at-startup