# DSL connection in WICD

Tags: network-manager, wicd, dsl

How can I configure DSL connection in WICD any Idea and if not use this then what should I use.

Answer (score 0):

Can provide info about DSL connection?
You wish connect adsl using pppoe or pppoa?
You dsl connection terminated to you on ethernet cabel or not?
Please give me more details.
Generally you can create pppoe connection on this way

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ADSLPPPoE

isp.lynx.net/support/download/pppoe/linux.pdf‎

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/wicd

But I find too many sites with complaints about wicd.
If you don't use NM meybe is better to fallow this

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ADSLPPPoE

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the help. I also found out one more solution wherein I was able to connect to my DSl/PPPoe connection with the help of the solution given below

http://askubuntu.com/questions/13674/how-to-connect-to-the-internet-dsl-automatically-at-startup